# Экранирование символов в регулярных выражениях в JAVA

Tags: eclipse, регулярные-выражения, java

Изучаю java. Пользуюсь eclipse. Хочу описать регулярное выражение, в котором должен участвовать символ `+`. Но `+` в регулярных выражениях - не просто `+`, а символ, имеющий определённое значение. Мне же нужен просто `+`. Я поискал в интернете информацию по этому поводу и экранировал его с помощью символа `\`. Но компилятор стал ругаться на `\`. Так что же делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заэкранировать и слэш, очевидно.

```
\\+
```

Comment: ахах, ну точно) спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Есть спецсимволы или, точнее, строковые литералы вроде `'\n'` `'\t'` `'\b'`. Во время компиляции они заменяются на соответствующие числовые коды. Вы написали `"\+"`, и компилятор пытается найти спецсимвол в языке программирования `'\+'`, он его не находит и потому ругается.

Потому нужно экранировать слеш, т.е. `"\\+"`, тогда в регулярное выражение подставится `"\+"`, что будет обработано как символ `'+'`.