# Regex для квадратных скобок

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Пытаюсь сделать регулярку для спец символов: ',', '.' и т.д. Но как быть с "[" и "]"?

Моя регулярка выглядит так: `String[] clean = input.split("[(),. !?:;]");`

И если туда вписать квадратные скобки, то все ломается.

Comment: Используйте обратный слэш. Типа `[\[\]]`

Comment: Кстати, по идее точка и знак вопроса тоже не дожны пройти из-за того, что это спецсимволы

Comment: они проходят:) просто квадратные скобки все портят

Comment: Просто есть в регулярке спецсимволы, такие как вопросительный знак, звёзочка, точка и т.д., если хочется, чтоб регулрка такие символы тоже находила, но они "коллапсируют" с спецсимволами, надо предворять их обратным слэшем, чтобы регулярка не считала их за "свои родные"

Comment: `[^\d\s\p{L}]` а чего нить такое в java не работает?

Answer (score 4):

Java использует последовательности `\Q`, `\E` чтобы обозначить участок регулярного выражения, который должен работать как есть, как он написан. Между ними точка это только точка, а звёздочка - только звёздочка и ничего больше. Это относится ко всем специальным символам. Помните что по правилам Java обратные слеши нужно удваивать:

```
String[] clean = input.split("[\\Q(),. !?:;[]\\E]");
```

Кроме ручного кодирования в Java есть специальный метод, который превращает строку в литеральное регулярное выражение:

```
// Pattern.quote(String s)
String[] clean = input.split("[" + Pattern.quote("(),. !?:;[]") + "]");
```

Если вам нужно экранировать один-два символа, то используйте обратные слеши. Но только там где это необходимо. В вашем примере (в описании символьного класса) символы `[]` экранировать надо, а `().?, !:;` не обязательно. Без [справочника](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) тут не обойтись:

```
String[] clean = input.split("[(),. !?:;\\[\\]]");
```

Comment: `().?` в символьных классах не надо экранировать.

Comment: Спасибо! Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так:

```java
String[] clean = input.split("[\\(\\)\\,\\.\\[\\] \\!\\?\\:\\;]");
```

Подробнее: [ТыЦ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/365954/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B2-java) и [Тыц](https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/java-regexp-escape-char)

Причем хочу обратить внимание, что `.`, `?` `(`,`)` - это тоже спец. символы зарезервированные RegExp, поэтому их тоже нужно экранировать обратным слешем.